# Does UV exposure cause deterioration to PVC pipe which can lead to catastrophic failure?

Tags: pvc

I've heard over the years that PVC should **never** be exposed to ultraviolet radiation, or the pipe will crumble and disintegrate. Though upon researching the subject, it seems as though UV radiation only reduces the impact strength of the pipe.  Is UV degradation is a real problem, or a half truth propagated by the internet.

According to an article by [United States Plastic Corp.](http://www.usplastic.com/) ([Is PVC and CPVC pipe UV resistant?](http://www.usplastic.com/knowledgebase/article.aspx?contentkey=774)), and a [technical bulletin](http://www.jmeagle.com/pdfs/Technical%20Bulletins/TB10SunlightEffectsonPVC.pdf) released by [JM Eagle](http://www.jmeagle.com/). Only the pipe's impact resistance is reduced, while both tensile strength and modulus showed no reduction.

While I know that painting, or wrapping the pipe can eliminate any damage. I wonder if it's even worth the effort to do so, in most situations? Since the pipe maintains it's pressure capacity and stiffness, is protection required if the pipe is in an area where it's not subject to physical damage? Can UV radiation alone, cause a catastrophic failure of the pipe?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where would you typically have large amounts of PVC exposed to sunlight?

Comment: @DA01 It's used for plumbing pool filters sometimes.

Comment: Ah! True. In my (admittedly extremely limited) experience, there are other parts of that system that tend to fail long before the PVC pipe does (namely the pump itself)

Comment: I thought gray PVC was rated for UV exposure.  Or is there another reason for the color difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work in an environment that has 384 54W T8 fluorescent lamps and one PVC pipe. The pipe was unwrapped and began failing (crumbling apart) in 9 years. It wouldn't have held up to a someone bumping into it for probably a year prior to that, either. Your conditions will probably be less extreme, but it's a good idea to wrap or paint your pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I found an abandoned length of PVC pipe in the corner of my yard a while back and it was so brittle that it practically shattered from the pressure of holding it in my hand.

This applies to basically all plastic. PVC, ABS, PEX, you name it. Plastics need to be protected from the sun or else they will embrittle. Paint them, or, better yet, use metal pipe in above-grade outdoor applications.

Comment: Some plastics specifically designed for outdoor use have UV inhibitors added to them and can hold up very well. These will be industrial or agricultural type products. But I agree about PVC pipe.

Comment: The inhibitors only last so long, though. They prolong a plastic's useful service life in the sun, but cannot make it indefinite, like you would have with something made out of metal or stone.

Comment: Agreed. But the difference is very pronounced. Without UV inhibitors, plastic will fall apart in less than 1 year. With UV inhibitors, it may last for 5 or 10 years, or maybe more.

Comment: Clear Polyethylene is particularly sensitive to UV unless you're getting the greenhouse stuff that has the UV inhibitors. Polycarbonate is highly resistant. Most plastics suffer from polymer debonding in the presence of UV.

Answer (score 2):

See also the paper "[UNI-TR-5-03: The Effects of Ultraviolet Aging on PVC Pipe](https://www.uni-bell.org/application/files/6014/5956/5837/The_Effects_of_Ultraviolet_Radiation_on_PVC_Pipe_.pdf)", by the Uni-Bell PVC Pipe Association.

Their research indicates that the sole performance characteristic adversely affected by sunlight exposure to pipe is impact resistance (the ability of the pipe to withstand a rapid external force or violent contact). UV discoloration does not effect the pressure capacity of the pipe, or the pipe stiffness (external load capacity).